# Kendo Grid, in dataBound call accessing original bound line

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

In a kendo ui grid, in the dataBound call, you can access the original data using the below

```
e.sender.dataSource._data
```

This looks like it's intended to be for internal use only, and it doesn't tell you which data row was used to generate the current line

My question is, is there any to access the original data inside this call?

I can think of two ways but neither is ideal

(1) Stick some data in a cell(s) and access it using the below

```
var rows = this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row");
var innerHTML = row.cells[row.cells.length -1].innerHTML;
```

You could put a Guid in here and use it to find the original row

(2) As above but json encode it so you get an object to deal with, the json object would contain everything needed

Is there a better way?

Incidentally, what am I trying to accomplish? The row I am binding to has an override cssclass for the row which controls the row's tds styling. I am setting it in the dataBound call. There may be a better way to accomplish this

thanks

---

OnaBai has answered this, here are the specifics.
NB I'm not stating this is the best way in general to do this, in my specific example its just easier

```
dataBound: function(e) 
{
    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
    {
        var row = rows[i];

        var dataSourceRow = this.dataSource.getByUid($(row).attr("data-uid"));
        $(row).addClass(dataSourceRow.RowCssClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using templates? About that `guid` there is a _`guid`_ already, it is called `uid` and you can use it for getting the row or given the row find which is it `uid`.

Comment: Yep, that worked :-) If you make this the answer I'll accept it, in the meantime I'll edit the question with the specifics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually such `GUID`. Each row has a unique id field called `uid` that is accessible both in the model via `uid` member as well at HTML level by doing `row.attr("data-uid")` or using [`jquery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

So, if you have your row element it would be something like:

```
var item = this.dataSource.getByUid($(row).data("uid"));
```

or even if `row` is already a jQuery object then:

```
var item = this.dataSource.getByUid(row.data("uid"));
```